# Error 500 when with perl cgi - but not any of the common pitfalls

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a very tricky to diagnose perl problem, that has been seriously hampering my ability to maintain a perl/cgi website. It usually occurs when editing a script - after a change I get error 500, and then after I revert it it wont work again unless I delete the file and start from scratch, however I currently have a state which it can be reproduced by the following simple two scripts which show just how crazy this bug is:

file1.pl

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
print "content-type: text/html\n\nIt works";
```

file2.pl

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
print "content-type: text/html\n\nIt works";
```

(Ie... they're identical)

server.com/cgi-bin/file1.pl works

server.com/cgi-bin/file2.pl results in error 500

Both files have the same size and md5 hash.
Both have the same permissions (755) and the same owner and group.
Both are in the correct folder (hosting supplied cgi-bin).
Both were uploaded in text mode.
Both work with local perl interpreters.

If i rename file1 -> file3, file2 -> file1, and file3->file2, (ie swapping both files), now file2.pl works and file1.pl doesn't. So my guess is some state is attached to the files themselves.

If i edit the files in filezilla and re-upload (eg add some whitespace after a semicolon), same behaviour occurs with the re-uploaded files.

My error 500 page is set to auto-retry using a meta refresh (in case of out memory errors, etc), and it doesn't go away after countless refreshes. It doesn't seem to matter which ones is accessed first.

I do not have access to the http error_log on this hosting so do not know the reason for the failure. The error also occurs without the "use error messages to browser" diagnostic line.

Can anyone give me a hint as to what this could be and help me fix it?

Comment: "I do not have access to the http error_log on this hosting" That makes things rather difficult...

Comment: How did you upload the file that works? `file1.pl`

Comment: This problem rings a bell... I'm sure I've read about it on SO or somewhere similar. Have you googled it?

Comment: yes I've googled it - I get hundreds of pages talking about "making sure 755" or "make sure ascii" or "make sure in configured cgi-bin", and all the other newbie mistakes I listed and checked for.

Comment: Both uploaded from ftp.

Comment: Try running the non-working ones through dos2unix

Comment: Just for fun and complete confusion... if you want to make the files truly identical, try making a hard link (with `ln`) to a file and then accessing via the hard link. Likewise, try symlinking to a file (with `ln -s`) and then accessing via the symlink. It may shed some light... somehow.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe can be either caused by some problem on your hosting provider side (some bad caching, or transparent proxies, or any other magic), or—and that is what I think it is—still caused by wrong file permissions or line breaks, even if your file manager reports that everything is good.

If I'm reading your description correctly you basically

- can put a script and it will work, but
- cannot edit it as it will stop working after that.

As you don't have shell access, just put the following small script to the same directory and run it (hope it will run as you are not going to edit it):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";

opendir( my $dirh, "." );
my @files = grep { -f $_; } readdir $dirh;
closedir $dirh;

foreach my $file (@files) {
    my @stat = stat $file;
    my ($dev,  $ino,   $mode,  $nlink, $uid,     $gid, $rdev,
        $size, $atime, $mtime, $ctime, $blksize, $blocks
    ) = stat($file);
    my $octmode = sprintf "%04o", $mode & 07777;
    print "$file\tmode=$octmode\tuid=$uid\tgid=$gid\tsize=$size\t";
    if ( -r $file ) {
        open( my $fh, $file );
        my $firstline = <$fh>;
        print $firstline =~ /\r\n/ ? "crlf\n" : "lf\n";
        close $fh;
    } else {
        print "can't read\n";
    }
}
```

It will show the *real* permissions, linebreaks, and size of the files—those taken from the server's filesystem, not which your FTP client shows.

Maybe it's worth adding MD5 or SHA1 hash calculation to this script but not sure if you have `Digest::MD5` or `Digest::SHA1` available.

If you see the same output for `test1.pl` and `test2.pl`, just go ahead and contact your hosting provider's support.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: the files don't use the same [newline convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).
You can check this (in a Unix shell) using [the `file` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29).

Comment: That seems unlikely if the files have the same hash.

Comment: I don't have access to a shell so I can't execute that command.- but they both have the same file size in bytes on the server, so it isn't a CRLF and LF mismatch.

Comment: Are any remote filesystems (NFS, CIFS, ...) being used? Which OS do you use to compare size and hash, and which OS does the webserver use?

Comment: Can you write a CGI script to compare file size, hash, and permissions of the two scripts? Something like atycnth's?

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to inspect the errorlog is a big headache.

Nevertheless, I suspect that the cause is still most likely line endings.  I would upload a script to examine all of your files like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use CGI qw(header);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
use File::stat;

print header('text/plain');

my $fmt = "%-15s %4s %4s %4s %7s %4s %4s\n";
printf $fmt, qw(File mode uid gid size lf crlf);
printf $fmt, map { '-' x $_ } $fmt =~ /(\d+)/g;

opendir my $dh, '.';
while ( my $file = readdir $dh ) {
    next unless -f $file;

    my $stat = stat $file;

    my %chars;
    my $data = do { local ( @ARGV, $/ ) = $file; <> };
    $chars{$1}++ while $data =~ /(\R)/g;

    printf $fmt, $file, sprintf( "%04o", $stat->mode & 07777 ), $stat->uid,
        $stat->gid, $stat->size, map { $_ // 0 } @chars{ "\n", "\r\n" };
}
```

Outputs:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

File            mode  uid  gid    size   lf crlf
--------------- ---- ---- ---- ------- ---- ----
env.cgi         0775    0    0     266   25    0
le.pl           0775  501    0     696   28    0
lineendings.pl  0755  501    0     516   30    0
mywiki.pl       0755  501    0  226947    0 6666
test.cgi        0755    0    0    2071   65    0
wiki.pl         0755    0    0  219231 6494    0
```

For additional testing, I would recommend executing each of the scripts using [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) and inspecting the error conditions if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, got help from user BOC as below:
"You may have problem with encoding of characters. Some editors replace some characters by very close characters when you save files (for example " by “). Try changing editor (notepad++ works well on windows). – BOC"
I downloaded and used Notepad++ instead of Notepad and Winword; It works now for me.